# which network mode should I use if want every machine to be connected

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a physical machine and two virtual machines in VB. I want to know which network mode will allow me to (have a network) and let any of the two machines be pingable to each other.

I tried NAT network, but it's not displayed on my physical machine. The bridge network only allows me to ping between the 2 VMs. NAT just maps to 1 IP, so it's not what I want. The Internet network also doesn't work. Host-only allows me to ping between the physical machine and the associated VM.

From reference, a bridged network should be the case.
My problem is that I lost my internet after I switched to a bridged network. Moreover, only an IPv6 address was assigned to my ubuntu. After reading [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/920563/virtualbox-vm-only-getting-ipv6-over-bridge-connection-how-to-get-ipv4-address)

I was able to get the IPv4 address. However, I was unsure because this IP was the same as when I used NAT mode. Since I lost my connection to the Internet and DHCP server, maybe my VM just maintained its IP in NAT mode?

According to the spec, every machine gets its IP from the DHCP server in a bridged network, and VM acts as a physical machine, just like the host. However, I can't find any possible IP in my host that may be assigned from the same DHCP server(if VM has 10.0.2.14 and netmask 255.255.255.0. I should be able to find an IP like 10.0.2.24 in my host)

```
Ubuntu
enp0s10: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.5.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.5.255
        inet6 2001:da8:801d:f39c:3e68:64fc:cc0d:918d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<
```

I have 4 NICs in my host machine. vEthernet(nat, no internet), WLAN, (VirtualBox host-only, VMware network adapter VMnet8). I guess the last 2 are not relevant here. I tried the first 2 but didn't work.

Comment: What host OS are you using?

Comment: Bridge networking should allow you to do this. If it doesn't, something is wrong and requires debugging.

Comment: @user1686 My host is windows 10. My VMs are windows server 2019 and Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have you tried to either attach your host's outbound interface to the bridge used by your VMs (so that they get out via bridging) or enable routing from your VMs to the upstream network and vice versa?

Comment: @Robidu since I only have 2 adapters and I have tried both, I think I should try the 2nd method. But I'm not sure how to do that. Are you referring to port forwarding? But port forwarding seems not available in bridged network. Can you give some details on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not referring to port forwarding as that would refer to inbound connections from an upstream network forwarded to an internal (private) network in conjunction with DNAT (destination network address translation).

Bridging ties multiple ports together, and depending on your setup, you either get an IP address assigned by an upstream DHCP server (if the outbound interface is a bridge port), or you need to set up a DHCP server yourself (if it's not). With routing you can either have VirtualBox handle DHCP, or you need to set up a DHCP server yourself.

tbc...

Comment: However, since I'm coming from Linux, I don't have even the faintest idea about how to do that on Windows (I was checking on general setups here) and would have to investigate that in order to be able to give you any viable pointers. However, if you are going for routing, make sure to enable masquerading as well, because you could run into unexpected obstacles if you don't (private addresses not being routed in public space, packets from foreign addresses not properly masqueraded/routed by the gateway, MAC filters in place upstream, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under computer manager, in device manager, I added legacy hardware so that a new NIC would appear in my host. In WALN, share this network with the new adapter. In VMs, I switched NIC to the new adapter. The problem is solved. In this case, I think I'm doing NAT in my host and bridge in my VMs. Anyway, hope this helps!

```
host:192.168.137.1
ping 192.168.137.209

Pinging 192.168.137.209 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.137.209: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.209: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.209: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

ping 192.168.137.67

Pinging 192.168.137.67 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.137.67: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.137.67: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128


ubuntu:192.168.137.209
ping 192.168.137.1
PING 192.168.137.1 (192.168.137.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.838 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.763 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.798 ms

windows server:192.168.137.67
ping 192.168.137.1

Pinging 192.168.137.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.137.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.137.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.137.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Answer (score 2):

Bridge networking should be enough.
Maybe some firewalls are the problem?

Try resetting the vm network stack. Edit -> Virtual Network Editor -> Restore Defaults

Comment: You may want to add the explaination that bridge mode places the VM in the network like any other device, and as such this should be enough, and that it will also get an IP address from the DHCP server if its not set to static, another thing that may be the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

In bridge each VM is directly connected to whatever hardware NIC of the HOST you select in the VirtualBox advanced settings for that VM.
And the VM's will get ip-addresses from the same DHCP server (e.g. your home-router) that serves your host. Or you manually assign the ip-address in the same range as the host is using.

Please note that bridge mode WON'T work with a WIFI adapter on the host. The VM's will get a simulated wired NIC and they will not be able to do Wifi authentication.

Comment: If I understand correctly, only vEther will work when I choose the name for bridged adapter. But since I don't have internet, do I need to manage bridge network in my VM. Using 2 network adapters in my VM to create a bridge adapter. One with internet(NAT or some other NIC that has internet), the other one that I want to use in bridge connection(the NIC bridge network gives). Then do some settings in the bridge adapter to gain network since internet will be lost after creation.